# How to set label in dataPoints chart on javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I want to make chart and set the label and value from database. I already get the data and convert to json object.
this is the default script to set the label ,

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var arrchartdata = JSON.parse('<?php print $a;?>');

var options = {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "GDP Growth Rate - 2016"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Growth Rate (in %)",
        suffix: "%",
        includeZero: false
    },
    axisX: {
        title: "Countries"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        yValueFormatString: "#,##0.0#"%"",
        dataPoints: [
        for (var i = 0; i <arrchartdata.length ; i++) {
            console.log(arrchartdata[i].MenuName);
        }
        { label: arrchartdata[0].MenuName, y: 10.09 },  
        { label: "Turks & Caicos Islands", y: 9.40 },   
        { label: "Nauru", y: 8.50 },
        { label: "Ethiopia", y: 7.96 }, 
        { label: "Uzbekistan", y: 7.80 },
        { label: "Nepal", y: 7.56 },
        { label: "Iceland", y: 7.20 },
        { label: "India", y: 7.1 }

        ]
    }]
};
$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);

}
</script>
```

I want to loop the label : arrchardata[0].MenuName, y : 10.09
How i can do  it?
I already tried for inside the data but it returns error.
Any help would appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

you'll have add the loop outside `options`, store result inside the variable then use the variable inside `options` as shown below.

I've stored in `dataPoints` variable.

```
var dataPoints = [];

for (var i = 0; i <arrchartdata.length ; i++) {
    console.log(arrchartdata[i].MenuName);
    dataPoints.push({label : arrchartdata[i].MenuName});
}

var options = {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "GDP Growth Rate - 2016"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Growth Rate (in %)",
        suffix: "%",
        includeZero: false
    },
    axisX: {
        title: "Countries"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        yValueFormatString: "#,##0.0#"%"",
        dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
};
$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);

}
</script>
```